# Распределение суммы на промежутки в Excel

Tags: алгоритм, функции, excel, математика, формулы

помогите создать формулу по которой будет производиться расчет в Excel.

---

Суть в следующем в бухгалтерской компании есть потребность создать гибкую систему тарифов. В зависимости от количества операций производимых клиентом компании в месяц, стоимость каждой последующей снижается. Допустим при совершении одной операции в месяц ее стоимость будет 300 рублей, а при десяти операциях стоимость каждой будет 200 рублей. Далее я укажу опорные точки с диапазонах между которыми нужно распределить стоимость операций промежуточных точек:

- При 1 операции - 300 рублей за каждую
- При 10 операциях - 200 рублей за каждую
- При 25 операциях - 175 рублей за каждую
- При 50 операциях - 150 рублей за каждую
- При 100 операциях - 145 рублей за каждую
- При 200 операциях - 135 рублей за каждую
- При 200 операциях - 120 рублей за каждую
- При 500 операциях - 105 рублей за каждую
- При более 1000 операций - 90 рублей за каждую

---

Дело в том что если не сделать формулу и в диапазонах оставлять значения контрольных точек, то стоимость услуг будет не логичной и с большим разбросом. 
Например:
 - при 499 операциях = 499*105 = 52395 рублей (вроде все нормально);
 - при 500 операциях = 500*105 = 52500 рублей (вроде пока тоже нормально);
 - при 501 операции = 501*90= 45090 рублей (почти на 7000 рублей дешевле, хотя работы на одну операцию больше).

---

Помогите пожалуйста, т.к. если забивать в ручную получиться очень громоздкая таблица, которую будет тяжело подцепить в калькулятор, который планируем сделать на сайте.
Спасибо.

Comment: *Допустим при совершении одной операции в месяц ее стоимость будет 300 рублей, а при десяти операциях стоимость каждой будет 200 рублей.* А вот фигушки. Первые 9 операций будут стоить по 300 (все 9 - 9*300=2700), операции 10-24 по 200 (все 24 - 9*300+(24-9)*200=5700), 25-49 по 175 (все 49 - 9*300+(24-9)*200+(49-24)*175=10075) и так далее.

Comment: Как я понял, нужна линейная зависимость суммы от количества. *Х* операций попадает в диапазон от *a1* до *a2*. Стоимость для этих границ *s1*  и *s2*: *a1/a2=s1/s2* вычисляется доля на единицу количества и определяется сумма. Это нужно? Функции *ТЕНДЕНЦИЯ, НАКЛОН, ЛИНЕЙН* - их нужно смотреть. ЭтМакрос принимается или нужен только формульный вариант?

Answer (score 0):

Можно все это разместить в одной формуле, но получится громоздкая и слабопонятная конструкция.

Итак. Первое, что нужно - таблица с граничными данными. Есть (столбцы *B:C*).

Чтобы найти скидку цены, нужно узнать стоимость одной операции в диапазоне, в который попало общее количество операций. Соответственно, для определения стоимости необходимо получить количество операций в диапазоне.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ячейка *F1*- количество операций, стоимость которых нужно определить.

Определяем границы диапазона - пороги количества и граничные значения стоимости.

Нижний порог (*F2*):

```
=ИНДЕКС(B2:B11;ПОИСКПОЗ(F1;B2:B11))
```

Верхний порог (*F3*):

```
=ЕСЛИ(F1>МАКС(B2:B11);МАКС(B2:B11);ИНДЕКС(B2:B11;ПОИСКПОЗ(F1;B2:B11)-СЧЁТЕСЛИ(B2:B11;F1)+1))
```

Сравнение с *МАКС* - для количества больше максимального порога, *СЧЁТЕСЛИ* помогает отследить точное совпадение с пороговым значением.

Стоимость для нижнего и верхнего порогов
 (*F5, F6*) определяется по найденным пороговым значениям:

```
=ВПР(F2;$B$2:$C$11;2;)

=ВПР(F3;$B$2:$C$11;2;)
```

Стоимость одной операции (*F7*) - простым математическим выражением:

```
=F5-(F5-F6)/(F3-F2+1)*(F1-F2))
```

Все. Полная стоимость (*F8*), как обычно - количество*цена:

```
=F1*F7
```

:)

Для мазохистов - все в одной ячейке (без оптимизаций и сокращений, почти 400 знаков в формуле)

```
=F1*(ВПР(ИНДЕКС(B2:B11;ПОИСКПОЗ(F1;B2:B11));$B$2:$C$11;2;)-(ВПР(ИНДЕКС(B2:B11;ПОИСКПОЗ(F1;B2:B11));$B$2:$C$11;2;)-ВПР(ЕСЛИ(F1>МАКС(B2:B11);МАКС(B2:B11);ИНДЕКС(B2:B11;ПОИСКПОЗ(F1;B2:B11)-СЧЁТЕСЛИ(B2:B11;F1)+1));$B$2:$C$11;2;))/(ЕСЛИ(F1>МАКС(B2:B11);МАКС(B2:B11);ИНДЕКС(B2:B11;ПОИСКПОЗ(F1;B2:B11)-СЧЁТЕСЛИ(B2:B11;F1)+1))-ИНДЕКС(B2:B11;ПОИСКПОЗ(F1;B2:B11))+1)*(F1-ИНДЕКС(B2:B11;ПОИСКПОЗ(F1;B2:B11))))
```